# Using Github Project in Docker

Tags: docker, github

I'm working on face detection project and trying to use [this](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) github project.
But the issue is I'm using windows system and have difficulties installing modules used in this project. I can use a VM, install linux and use it. But can I use docker to call the project from github and work with it? If yes, how to do it? I tried to read about it, but hardly got any materials.

Thank you!

Comment: It is perfectly possible to run Docker for Windows. It is officially supported on 64 bit platform, and possible to run it on 32 bit Win 7 also - I do it. With some googling you can find the article about doing this installation for 32 bit, it is manual but can be done, maybe not painless, I do not remember, usually there are some pain with experiments. And there is even an installer for the 64 bit which I currently do not have.

Comment: @HoZong: THanks for your comment! I already installed docker in my windows system. But don't know how to call github repositories into the docker container and work with it. Thanks!

Comment: For this I created a docker hub account, and import the GitHub project there. Then you can just use `docker pull`. And it is also possible to checkout a project and do `docker build` there, but then you are using your own computer's resources.

Comment: @HoZong: Thanks a lot! I'll try this option.